# Firebase Crashlytics; misleading crash count?

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

I'm using Firebase as my backend and I've have an app running in production, which I'm monitoring crashes for in Crashlytics.

Because my app uses bitcode, I upload the dSYM's manually after releasing the app. In the "dSYMs"-tab of Crashlytics in the Firebase console, I see the following "Crash count":

[image: Screenshot of Firebase Crashlytics dSYMs tab, showing "Crash count"]

**What does this "Crash count" mean?**

When looking at the Crashlytics dashboard I see a completely different picture of my app:

[image: Screenshot of Firebase Crashlytics Dashboard tab, showing "Crash count"]

For now I'll believe that only one crash happened, but these mystical 1051 crashes aren't very reassuring...

Comment: you have a filter of last 7 days, maybe they happened earlier

Comment: Nope, that doesn't change anything. The build has been live in less than 7 days.

Comment: does your crashlitics is linked with fabric? If yes, you could check their console for a more info

Comment: may be your app is crash in same device and same position at many time so that's real only crash but it's crash multiple time..

Comment: It is linked directly to Firebase. I don't how I can log into Fabric, the google account that Firebase is configured with doesn't work on Fabric.

Comment: then the best thing would be to write to google, all other stuff looks ok :)

Comment: @SagarBhut Maybe... But it sound a bit unlikely, that would have been one very eager user..

Comment: @Taier I guess your right.. I'll try that.

Comment: I've filed a bug report.. I'll post the answer here if one arrives.

Comment: Hi, Paul from Crashlytics here. Does the count in your dashboard continue to stay at 1 after you upload the missing dSYM?

Comment: @buser Hi Paul, I've got the same issue. In my case the count in my dashboard reads 0 but the crash count is the same non-zero value before and after uploading the dSYM.